# I founded my LLC in October 2014 but my business still isn't active. Do I need to file taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company

Started the business in late October but did no work in 2014. My business is licensed in Texas. Do I need to file taxes for my business?

Comment: Good thing you're not in VT, businesses pay a minimum $250 income tax no matter what.

Comment: "Started" the company?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. Your business is *active* since it was established, it just didn't do anything.

This is of course re the State taxes, the IRS considers LLC as a disregarded entity and it flows directly to your Schedule C if you're a single member, or your 1065 if you're multiple members.

State of Texas never considers LLC as a disregarded (See here [questions 13 and 14](http://www.window.state.tx.us/taxinfo/franchise/faq_tax_ent.html)). You may not pay any taxes, but you have to file.

Comment: Well, it seems like a reasonable question, since for an individual, if you have no income during the year, you're generally not required to file a tax return.  So you're saying there is no similar exception for an LLC?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not familiar with any such exception for a business.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: That wouldn't be surprising - I'm not from USA, but I've also seen inactive businesses required to file "zero reports" - properly signed tax papers that certify that you had 0 turnover.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a single-member LLC that is [treated as a disregarded entity](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Single-Member-Limited-Liability-Companies) (i.e. you didn't elect to be taxed as a corporation), and that LLC had no activity, you're off the hook for federal reporting.

The LLC's activity would normally be reported on your personal tax return on a Schedule C. If the LLC had under $400 in taxable earnings, no Schedule C is needed. [So an inactive LLC does not have a tax reporting requirement.](http://info.legalzoom.com/need-file-tax-return-llc-activity-3621.html) (If you had taxable income but under $400, you include that amount on your 1040 but don't need a Schedule C.)

In Texas, you still must file a Texas [franchise tax report](http://www.michaelplaks.com/free-irs-tax-advice/articles-business-entity/texas-franchise-tax) every year, even for a single-member LLC with no activity.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure in the beginning so went to verify. This is incorrect. Limited liability company is **never** a disregarded entity in Texas.